# How to set gravity in a linearlayout in recyclerview?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

[image]i  am working with recyclerview and i want to set gravity of a Linearlayout left or right in recyclerview .but my Linearlayout alwayas set in left my code is shown below.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MessageWindowHolder holder, int position) {
        if(notificationDescriptions.get(position).getIsRecieve())
        {
            holder.linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            holder.messageTextview.setText(notificationDescriptions.get(position).getMessage());
            holder.messageTextview.setBackground(notificationDescriptionActivity.getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.bubble_a)));
        }
        else {
            holder.linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.messageTextview.setText(notificationDescriptions.get(position).getMessage());
            holder.messageTextview.setBackground(notificationDescriptionActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_b));
        }

    }
```

notification_message.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_a"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Hello bubbles!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

viewholder.java

```
public class MessageWindowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected LinearLayout linearLayout;
    protected TextView messageTextview;


    public MessageWindowHolder(View view, List<NotificationDescription> notificationDescriptions) {
        super(view);
        this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
        this.messageTextview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singleMessage);
    }
}
```

Main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mindefy.kidster.activity.NotificationDescriptionActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_notification_description">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notificationRecyclerViewParent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageEdittext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
   />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendMessageEdittext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageReplyButton"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the code of your `ViewHolder` please.

Comment: check ViewHolder code

Comment: You want text to be set to right or left or the layout ...

Comment: i want to set layout left or right

Comment: Verify whether notificationDescriptions.get(position).getIsRecieve() is not returning true everytime

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The only problem could be your `getIsRecieve()` method always returning `true`.

Comment: Your code works fine , i made the gravity change according to the position and it works fine. You need to check method getIsRecieve() if its sending the correct expected value

Comment: @sJy ,i will check

Comment: its not always return true,this method works fine

Comment: can you share screenshot & main layout which contains the recyclerview?

Comment: i update main layout ,please check

Comment: Still suspect that your IF condition is always true. Try changing that condition like if(position%2 == 0) to do a test. Also do a clean & rebuild too.

Comment: still its not working

Answer (score 1):

Your code is well, but I think try this..

```
   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
   lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
    holder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

UPDATE : Another way to do this :

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

holder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)holder.linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity= Gravity.LEFT;

Hope it will work :)GlbMP

Answer (score 1):

`SetGravity` of `LinearLayout` sets `layout_gravity` of `LinearLayout`  in his parent. Change `singleMessageContainer` width from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`  . And this will work

**Update** : use `Gravity.End` and `Gravity.Start`

Answer (score 0):

To place the view on the right side of the RecyclerView, you must wrap the layout of the outgoing chat message in a simple layout and set the child's layout_gravity to "end":

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_a"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Hello bubbles!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
</FrameLayout>
```